# Is this the same subspace? integrable functions and continuous functions

Tags: real-analysis, integration, vector-spaces

The set of real-valued continuous functions on R is vector space, V.

The integrable AND real-valued, continuous functions is a subspace, W of V.

(The "integrable functions" isn't a subspace, because integrable function might not be continuous!)

A different vector space is the real-valued, integrable functions, call it F.

The continuous, AND integrable, real-valued functions are subspace of F... is this set W again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the difference between "integrable and real-valued and continuous" and "continuous and integrable and real-valued"? No matter how you permute these adjectives, they still define the same vector space, which injects as a sub-vector space into both $V$ and $F$. So the answer is yes, and $W$ is actually the intersection of $F$ and $V$, if we see them as sub-vector spaces of the vector space of all real-valued functions.

Comment: I guess it was bothering me because W is a subspace of non-identical vector spaces or V subspace of F? I think I know counter examples for both ways.

Comment: $W$ is a subspace of both $F$ and $V$, but neither $F$ nor $V$ is contained in the other. Well, depending on the setting: if you are only considering functions on the closed unit interval, for instance, then continuous implies (Riemann) integrable, hence $F$ contains $V$. But in general, this does not need to be the case.

Comment: OK that what I thought and I think it's really kind of strange. The subspace is the intersection of the two vector spaces.

Comment: Exactly, but it's really not so strange. You are just intersecting sets. The set of elements that satisfy property $A$ intersected with the set of elements that satisfy property $B$ is exactly the set of elements that satisfy both properties $A$ and $B$.

Comment: Or think of it geometrically, in three-dimensional space: the $z-$line is the intersection of the plane $x=0$ with the plane $y=0$, and the points on the line are exactly the points that satisfy both conditions $x=0$ and $y=0$. The $z-$line is a subspace of both planes, but no plane is contained in the other.