# Non-identical vector spaces V and W both share a subspace F. Must there be a vector space that contains both V and W?

Tags: vector-spaces

I'm looking for a counterexample because I don't see any reason why this must be true.

F is a subspace of W

F is a subspace of V

$V \not\subset W$, $W \not\subset V$, and $V \neq W$

And there is no vector space that contains both V and W.

I was thinking about continuous functions and integrable functions... but they are all functions. No good. Maybe it's much too hard (too general) to show that there isn't a vector space that contains V and W as subspaces because there are just too many possibilities?

Things that don't work:

1. $\forall a,b \in R$ vectors of the form  (a,0,0) are a subspace of (a,b,0) and (a,0,b) but both of those are subspaces of R3.
2. [Is this the same subspace? integrable functions and continuous functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3614264/is-this-the-same-subspace-integrable-functions-and-continuous-functions/3614270#3614270) <- they are all functions

Comment: This is not clear.  By $V_1\subset V_2$, do you just mean "$V_1$ is isomorphic to a subspace of $V_2$"?  or what?  If you have a concrete situation in mind, you should describe that.

Comment: No I mean they are NOT subsets of each other they just overlap at F.

Comment: If you can find a basis for $F$ and expand it to basis of $V$ and $W$ You have automatically found a vector space containing both of them, that is the generated space of the union of the basis

Comment: What does "overlap" mean if they aren't sitting in some specified universal space?

Comment: For $V$ and $W$ to "share" a subspace, you have to be talking about them both already living in a larger space. Otherwise, they just both have an embedded copy of the "shared" space. If you are only talking about embedded copies, then I think you can easily construct a space containing copies of $V$ and $W$

Comment: If you have any two vector spaces $V,W$ then $V\oplus W$ is a vector space that "contains" both $V$ and $W$.  Is that good enough?

Comment: THANK YOU EXODD that makes sense.

Comment: BTW, do you mean to have that $F=V\cap W$ ? Is that what you mean by "overlap"?

Comment: There might be something in the intersection of V and W that isn't in F. F is just a subspace of V and of W.

Comment: $F \subseteq V \cap W$